# WinRT - Adding new item to XML and Acces denied

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a simple task application. I have taskTextBox, addButton, and tasksListView where are tasks displayed. I'm adding new item to XML file this way:

```
    private async void addButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("tasks.xml");
            var readStream = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            var writeStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

            XElement xElem = XElement.Parse(readStream);

            xElem.Add(new XElement("Task",
                new XElement("Id", Guid.NewGuid()),
                new XElement("Name", QuickTaskTextBox.Text.ToString())
            ));

            xElem.Save(writeStream);

            taskTextBox.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new MessageDialog(ex.Message).ShowAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyTasks));
        }
    }
```

but when I clcik on addButton then application throws exception access denied HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

it is caused by this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyTasks)); when I delete this code then everithing looks OK only ListView doesn't contains my new added task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably change the page so that it does not navigate to itself.

However, ignoring that for a moment, you have another problem.  You never explicitly close your file. This means that if your page navigates to itself fast enough, that the file you are trying to open is still open. This causes the access denied error.  To fix that you need to wrap the usage of `writeStream` in a `using` statement:

```
var readStream = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
using (var writeStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    XElement xElem = XElement.Parse(readStream);

    xElem.Add(new XElement("Task",
        new XElement("Id", Guid.NewGuid()),
        new XElement("Name", QuickTaskTextBox.Text.ToString())
    ));

    xElem.Save(writeStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like this is all one page (i.e., your code appears in the page `MyTasks`), and you're navigating from the page back to itself?  I'd have thought that would be a problem in itself, but it does seem to work in at least a simplistic case for me.  So I'm not sure where the exception is thrown, unless something in your `OnNavigatedTo` doesn't like the fact you're navigating back to the same page.

Bottom line, I'd advise against this approach, you're tearing down and recreating the page and the underlying class when you do that.

When you are adding the item to the XML stream, add an element to the collection of tasks that is the `ItemsSource` of the ListView control.  Presuming that's an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) you'll see the addition reflected without having to do something as disruptive as reload the page (which I assume just re-reads the file you just wrote?)